# How do I start my project in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I've tried to create my new Unreal Engine 5 project from a tutorial with c++ and when I try it comes up with this:

```
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.0EA/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/lubo/Desktop/Unreal/Unreal Projects/SecondProject/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.0EA\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [C:\Program Files\dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].

The .NET Core runtime can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

I've already installed it and tried all I can but it still comes up with the error.

Comment: Search for the error message online, chances are you are not the first to encounter such an error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hostfxr.dll+could+not+be+found. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the dotnet sdk to see if this resolves magically somehow
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-3.1.418-windows-x64-installer

The assembly probing will then be able to resolve the binary.